# Is it possible to use gmail as the smtp server for sending e-mail from ExpressionEngine?

Tags: smtp, email

Is it possible to use gmail as the smtp server for sending e-mail out from ExpressionEngine? It looks like you need to be able to set a different port and i'm not sure you can do it from the  E-mail config page in the EE admin area?

Comment: Do you specifically want to use Gmail, or would you be open to the idea of using a transactional email service like Sendgrid or Mandrill? Only reason I ask this, is I have a lot of experience using other email services within EE, just no experience with Gmail.

Comment: Gmail specifically, especially without using a third party add-on, i'm sure you must be able to do this natively in the config.php somewhere perhaps?...

Comment: I won't make this an official answer, as it's untested and more or less a suggestion. But go to Admin > Email Configurations and enter your SMTP information for Gmail. I bet that works. If so, answer your own question based on my comments (or I can make an official answer).

Comment: Why are you using Gmail to send email? If you are just testing, use MailTrap.io. If you are looking for a cheap/free production solution, use Mandrill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Google's move toward [stricter security measures regarding how third-parties connect with their services](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html), there's now another step required to set up ExpressionEngine to send email through Gmail. Beginning to end, here's how to do it.

### Step 1: Allow "Less Secure Apps" to Access Gmail

Sign in to the Gmail (or Gmail-powered Google Apps) account you want to use and open up the ["less secure apps" section](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) under My Account.

Turn on access for less secure apps.

### Step 2: Configure ExpressionEngine

In your config.php file, copy over these config items and modify the username and password. Note that the username *must* be the full email address, and the value for `$config['email_newline']` *must* be enclosed in double quotes.

```
$config['mail_protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['email_newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['email_smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
$config['smtp_server'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_username'] = 'username@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_password'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
```

This has been tested thoroughly in ExpressionEngine 2.10.1, though given the availability of [config overrides](http://ee2docs.com/general/system_configuration_overrides.html), it should work with EE 2.6+. For older versions, just omit the line for `$config['email_smtp_crypto']` and use `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` as the value for `$config['smtp_server']`.

### Step 3: Test

Make sure it works before you push these changes live. I haven't tested in all possible network configurations or with all possible EE versions. If you find a scenario that requires something different, drop it in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure because of Gmail's forced use of SSL connections this work around is still required in EE 2.  I don't remember this being corrected in recent releases of EE v2 but I could be mistaken:

https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/169641/is-smtp-configuration-for-gmail-possible

Comment: It would be great if someone could copy the actual workaround here, rather than linking to a forum thread people need to dig through to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for you or not, but I was able to set up Google smtp over TLS with a few additions to the config:

```
$env_conf['mail_protocol']    = 'smtp';
$env_conf['smtp_server']      = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:XXX';    // Use :XXX to set the port number.
$env_conf['smtp_username']    = 'xxx@xxx.xxx';
$env_conf['smtp_password']    = 'xxx';
$env_conf['email_newline']    = "\r\n";
$env_conf['email_crlf']       = "\r\n";
$config['smtp_port'] = "xxx"; //replace with your port number
```

In my particular case I just added the last 3 to a config bootstrap and set up the rest through the cpanel.

Most of this came from this Gist https://gist.github.com/experience/2557044 and the EE hidden config vars docs: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#smtp-port

Hopefully that works for someone :)